# Combine multiple log files to archive using PoSh and 7zip

Tags: powershell, logging, archive, 7zip

I am trying to join multiple log files into a single archive file, then move that archive file to another location, in an effort to both clean up old log files, and save hard drive space. We have a bunch of tools that all log to the same root, with a per-tool folder for their logs. (E.g.,

1. C:\ServerLogs
2. C:\ServerLogs\App1
3. C:\ServerLogs\2ndApp

each of which will have log files inside, like

1. C:\ServerLogs\App1\June1.log
2. C:\ServerLogs\App1\June2.log
3. C:\ServerLogs\2ndApp\June1.log
4. C:\ServerLogs\2ndApp\June2.log

I want to go into each of these subfolders, archive up all the files older than 5 days, then move the archive to another (long-term storage) drive and delete the now-zipped files. The tools I'm using are PowerShell and 7zip. The below code is using test locations.

I have cobbled together two scripts from various sources online, over the course of two full shifts, but neither one works right. Here's the first:

```
# Alias for 7-zip 
if (-not (test-path "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe")) {throw "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe needed"} 
set-alias 7zip "$env:ProgramFiles\7-Zip\7z.exe" 
$Days = 5 #minimum age of files to archive; in other words, newer than this many days ago are ignored
$SourcePath = C:\WorkingFolder\FolderSource\
$DestinationPath = C:\Temp\
$LogsToArchive = Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).addDays(-$Days)}
$archive = $DestinationPath + $now + ".7z"

#endregion

foreach ($log in $LogsToArchive) {
    #define Args
    $Args = a -mx9 $archive $log
    $Command = 7zip
    #write-verbose $command

    #invoke the command
    invoke-expression -command $Command $Args
```

The problem with this one is that I get errors trying to invoke the expression. I've tried restructuring it, but then I get errors because my $Args have an "a"

So I abandoned this method (despite it being my preferred), and tried this set.

```
#region Params
param(
    [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'container'})]
    [System.String]
    $SourceDirectory,
    [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
    [System.String]
    $DestinationDirectory
)
#endregion

function Compress-File{
    #region Params
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path -Path $_ -PathType 'leaf'})]
        [System.String]
        $InputFile,
        [Parameter(Position=1, Mandatory=$true)]
        [ValidateNotNullOrEmpty()]
        [System.String]
        $OutputFile
    )
    #endregion

    try{
        #Creating buffer with size 50MB
        $bytesGZipFileBuffer = New-Object -TypeName byte[](52428800)

        $streamGZipFileInput = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream($InputFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Open,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Read)
        $streamGZipFileOutput = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.FileStream($OutputFile,[System.IO.FileMode]::Create,[System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)
        $streamGZipFileArchive = New-Object -TypeName System.IO.Compression.GZipStream($streamGZipFileOutput,[System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode]::Compress)

        for($iBytes = $streamGZipFileInput.Read($bytesGZipFileBuffer, 0,$bytesGZipFileBuffer.Count);
            $iBytes -gt 0;
            $iBytes = $streamGZipFileInput.Read($bytesGZipFileBuffer, 0,$bytesGZipFileBuffer.Count)){

            $streamGZipFileArchive.Write($bytesGZipFileBuffer,0,$iBytes)
        }

        $streamGZipFileArchive.Dispose()
        $streamGZipFileInput.Close()
        $streamGZipFileOutput.Close()

        Get-Item $OutputFile
    }
    catch { throw $_ }
}


Get-ChildItem -Path $SourceDirectory -Recurse -Exclude "*.7z"|ForEach-Object{
    if($($_.Attributes -band [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory) -ne [System.IO.FileAttributes]::Directory){
        #Current file
        $curFile = $_

        #Check the file wasn't modified recently
        if($curFile.LastWriteTime.Date -le (get-date).adddays(-5)){

            $containedDir=$curFile.Directory.FullName.Replace($SourceDirectory,$DestinationDirectory)

            #if target directory doesn't exist - create
            if($(Test-Path -Path "$containedDir") -eq $false){
                New-Item -Path "$containedDir" -ItemType directory
            }

            Write-Host $("Archiving " + $curFile.FullName)
            Compress-File -InputFile $curFile.FullName -OutputFile $("$containedDir\" + $curFile.Name + ".7z")
            Remove-Item -Path $curFile.FullName
        }
    }
}
```

This actually seems to work, insofar as it creates individual archives for each eligible log, but I need to "bundle" up the logs into one mega-archive, and I can't seem to figure out how to `recurse` (to get sub-level items) and do a `foreach` (to confirm age) without having that `foreach` produce individual archives.

I haven't even gotten into the Move and Delete phase, because I can't seem to get the archiving stage to work properly, but I certainly don't mind grinding away at that once this gets figured out (I've already spent two full days trying to figure this one!).

I greatly appreciate any and all suggestions! If I've not explained something, or been a bit unclear, please let me know!

EDIT1: Part of the requirement, which I completely forgot to mention, is that I need to keep the structure in the new location. So the new location will have

1. C:\ServerLogs     -->   C:\Archive\
2. C:\ServerLogs\App1     -->   C:\Archive\App1
3. C:\ServerLogs\2ndApp     -->   C:\Archive\2ndApp
4. C:\Archive
5. C:\Archive\App1\archivedlogs.zip
6. C:\Archive\2ndApp\archivedlogs.zip
   And I have absolutely no idea how to specify that the logs from App1 need to go to App1.

EDIT2: For this latter part, I used Robocopy - It maintains the folder structure, and if you feed it ".zip" as an argument, it'll only do the .zip files.

Comment: i think this line `$Args = a -mx9 $archive $log` needs to have the value wrapped in double quotes OR each non-variable wrapped in quotes with a comma between each so that you get an array of args. ///// also, why not use the built in commands? see `Get-Command *archive*` for the list.

Comment: You can use [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators) instead of invoke-expression: `foreach ($log in $LogsToArchive) { & 7zip a -mx9 $archive $log }`

Comment: @JamesC. I tried that, and I got (for each eligible log file) a "Warning: The system cannot find the file specified" and (oddly!) an empty archive in the target destination. Which, on balance, is progress of a sort!

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I'll have a bit of playtime with quotes on the arguments, but as for using 7zip, that was dictated by higher-ups, so I'm stuck with it (I think it was a question of performance, maybe?). But I'll try to fiddle with it and see if I can't get "Compresss-Archive" to accept multiple files into one archive.

Comment: @RSchreib - you may have to move the files into one dir to get them into one archive without lots of fiddling. as for the builtin archive cmdlets ... they are always there in ps4+ [or maybe 3], so it's a more predictable thing to use.

Comment: if you could use `Compress-Archive` instead of 7zip, your code would be very simple: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Path $SourcePath -Include *.txt | Where-Object {$_.lastwritetime -le (get-date).addDays(-$Days)} |  Compress-Archive -DestinationPath (Join-Path $DestinationPath "$((Get-Date).ToString('yyyyMMdd')).zip")`

Comment: Gents, I took your advice, and I've pushed back against leadership and told them we need to use Compress-Archive. James, thanks for that snippet, I'll be using that, once I figure out how to make it do the things I mentioned in the Edit above. Maybe a Foreach loop with a Where-Object $_.PSIsContainer

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Your first reply was the right answer. I needed to wrap the arguments in double quotes: `$args = "a", "-mx9", "-tzip", "$archive", "$log"` 

Also, we needed to use 7-zip because the built-in commands are limited to 2GB files. Thanks a million!

Comment: @RSchreib - thank you for the info! i was quite curious about the situation ... [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey I've been using Stack Overflow a bit more, and I'd like you to get credit for the answer, but I'm not sure how to "promote" a comment into an answer that I can accept. Any ideas? and thanks again! I've been able to use this "technique" a few other times, now, too, with other commands/external applications.

Comment: @RSchreib - you can't, from what i can tell. [*grin*] let me add an "answer" and - if it looks like the proper answer, you can upvote that one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this line `$Args = a -mx9 $archive $log` likely needs to have the right side value wrapped in double quotes OR each non-variable wrapped in quotes with a comma between each so that you get an array of args.

another method would be to declare an array of args explicitly. something like this ...

```
$ArgList = @(
    'a'
    '-mx9'
    $archive
    $log
    )
```

---

i also recommend you NOT use an automatic $Var name. take a look at `Get-Help about_Automatic_Variables` and you will see that `$Args` is one of those. you are strongly recommended NOT to use any of them for anything other than *reading*. writing to them is iffy. [*grin*]